# Image centered above text

Tags: css, html, centering

I would like to create an effect similar to the Meet us/find us/follow us/ask us/latest items text with images centered above the text, on the website below.

(http://www.albamclothing.com/)

I have experimented with tables, and have a 2 column vertical div but the text and the image are never aligned precisely.

I have tried text align center, which works to an extent but not for multiple images.

Comment: please post yourcodes that you have built so far here

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave us the programmer used

1. a div with `text-align:center;`
2. an image inside it
3. a span with equal width to that of the div AND `float:left;`
4. inside the span is the text.

Try repeating that maybe?